# How accurate is pytesseract for reading computer generated images containing popular digital font?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to translate images of texts using tesseract. The results seems accurate from my trials. However it seems that I can also train tesseract to be more accurate although complicated.

My question is, how reliable out-of-box tesseract for image to text function for digital images containing popular font like times new roman, arial, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It usually depends on the content of the image - if there's some noise or just unrelated to text background (logos/tables/just random things) - the quality would drop, especially if the contrast of text vs noise is not big enough.

It also depends on the text size: if you have multiple text areas with different font size - you'd most likely need to process those separately (or figure out if different PSM mode could help you), so it would be hard to prepare a generic solution which would work in all cases.

In general - you can visit [Tessereact: how to improve quality](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality) page and try to follow all the instructions there.

Comment: Follow up: quality wise, I think it's been reliable, what would you recommend to do to increase reading speed? I'm now at 24 sec per page and would like to decrease it to 1 sec or less if possible.

Comment: In order to improve performance - you'd need to rescale your image or crop text & then rescale that.

Comment: Another option is to use different tessdata - tesseract allows you to use a faster (and less accurate) files - check the `tessdata fast` repository